# MariaDB Bundy System

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am storing start and finish session timestamps on a table called 'records' [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eKHr.png)

An individual can sign in and out multiple times in a day.

I'd like to tally up the total time accummulated each day, and display the total seconds each day. The result should have the columns EmployeeID and a column for each day. Where there are no log in or out records, it should state 0.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBgBv.png)

Comment: Hi, can you please post your data in here directly instead of linking to a picture of it? :)

Comment: Hi jBuchholz, I've placed a sql output of the current table https://flourish.escu.com.au/records.sql

Comment: As you post the 'finish', compute the time.  The rest of the work will much easier.